# Cannot debug my Monotouch application anymore and it gets stuck randomly

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to debug my application and from the point I fire it up on the iPad, it will get killed by timeout before it ever reaches FinishedLaunching() (I have abreakpoint there)! Here' swhat I see in the output panel. All this takes almost 20s.
If I run the app in RELEASE build it randomly gets stuck. I hit a button and the delegate gets caled half a minute later. What is going on? In the Simulator it is all okay.

```
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/monotouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/iMy.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C3E70D7B-8C10-49CD-98A7-FCE857899BAA/MyBrowser.app/MyBrowser.exe
Thread started: 
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'AppDelegateIPad.cs:110' to Boolean MyBrowser.AppDelegateIPad:FinishedLaunching ():0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid setting breakpoints in FinishedLaunching. When compiling in Debug mode, the code is always slower. On the simulator it works because:
a. There is no wifi connection between "device" and MonoDevelop
b. The "device" is your computer, so everything runs faster than it would on the actual device.

If it randomly gets stuck in Release mode, I think you have a lot going on in FinishedLaunching that you shouldn't.

Comment: It does not get stuck in FinishedLaunching, but in various places. The debugging is indeed the WiFi's fault. It works fine at home but not at work. Could it be some firewall setting or seomthing on my work's Mac which I don't have on my notebook?
The breakpint in FinishedLaunching I only set to prove that it never even gets there and that would be the first chance to break.

Comment: Yes a firewall blocking the incoming ports would be an issue. Check that the ports that MonoDevelop listens on are open.

Comment: But then it would work - or not. But not slow...I think it really is my connection at work as I have no issues here at home.